# awk if command that works to print column 19 only but how would i get it to print both columns?

Tags: awk

I want to print column 3 and 4 but without printing the headers empty column lines.

```
header
tap
norm 
X Y       880 1787
X Y       3253 3439
```

Printing this via `awk '{print($3,$4)}'` gives

```
(BLANK lines from header rows)
880 1787
3253 3439
```

This works to print column 19 only but how would I get it to print both columns?

```
awk  '$3{print $3}' 
880
3253
```

I want col3 col4

```
880 1787
3253 3439
```

I tried but get only column 3 printed

```
awk '$3{print $3}''$4{print $4}' 
880
1787
3253
3439
```

Comment: It is easier to get the help you need if you provide the contents of the file you're working with. What do mean by empty column lines? If you just want to print both columns then the `man` page for `awk` or google will help you. You're on the right track.

Comment: Please format example input and output with code formatting. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help/#code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know how long the head is (three lines):

```
awk 'NR > 3 { print $3, $4 }'
```

`NR` is the number of records (lines by default) that has been read so far.  With `NR > 3` we trigger the `print` statement for the fourth line and all lines after.

You *could* use

```
awk '$3 { print $3, $4 }'
```

but this is a bit fragile as it depends on not only `$3` being present but also that it is non-zero (a zero in the third column would give no output for that line).

Answer (score 0):

If

```
header
tap
norm
X Y 880 1787
X Y 3253 3439
```

Then

```
awk '{print $3 " " $4}' | sed '/^ *$/d'
```

Makes

```
880 1787
3253 3439
```

And for your last part you can try

```
 awk '{print $3 " " $4 " " $19}'
```

To print the 3rd, 4th and 19th columns.